# Change index column to real column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I had an original DataFrame that looked like this:

```py
    column0                              column2
0         0 SomethingSomeData1MixedWithSomeData2
1 something            SomeMoreDataWithSomeData3
2  whatever                            SomeData4
```

From that, I needed to extract the regex `(SomeData\d)`, which let me to use `df[column2].str.extractall()`, with the following results:

```py
             data
  match
0     0 SomeData1
0     1 SomeData2
1     0 SomeData3
2     0 SomeData4
```

What I actually need is to have something like this:

```py
      data0     data1
0 SomeData1 SomeData2
1 SomeData3
2 SomeData4
```

It can also be something like:

```py
                    data
0 [SomeData1, SomeData2]
1            [SomeData3]
2            [SomeData4]
```

I've tried to use `df[column2].str.split()`, but it created a list on the column and kept all of the other stuff that wasn't needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.findall` instead of `str.extractall`:

```
>>> df['column2'].str.findall('SomeData\d')
0    [SomeData1, SomeData2]
1               [SomeData3]
2               [SomeData4]
Name: column2, dtype: object
```

A quick but not optimized way is to use `apply` on each row:

```
>>> df['column2'].str.findall('SomeData\d').apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('data')
       data0      data1
0  SomeData1  SomeData2
1  SomeData3        NaN
2  SomeData4        NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You should just [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) the output of [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html):

```
(df['column2'].str.extractall('(SomeData\d)')[0]
 .unstack('match', fill_value='')
 .add_prefix('data')
 .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
       data0      data1
0  SomeData1  SomeData2
1  SomeData3           
2  SomeData4
```